# How to make sum of elements in the xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xslt like this:

```
<Node>

<xsl:for-each select="A">
 <item>
  //some operations
 </item>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="B">
 <item>
   <Number></Number>
 </item>
</xsl:for-each>

<item>
 <SumOfNumberOfB></SumOfNumberOfB>   
</item>

</Node>
```

I need to sum all the numbers from xslt node `Number` and show them in `SumOfNumberOfB`. I can't take it from the xml which I'm using because there are problems with rounding. So it need to be in xslt.

**EDIT**

So in the xml I have numbers like this 12.3267 for B with 4 digits after the decimal separator. In the Number the numbers must be rounded to 12.32. The same is for the SumOfNumberOfB, if I wrote sum(//B/Number) and after that I round it to 2 in some cases there is difference in the sums.

> Sum:
> 12.1237 + 12.1568 = 24.2805 -> After Rounding 24.28
>
> Rounding in the B:
> 12.12 + 12.15 = 24.27
>
> 24.28 is different from 24.27.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I can't take it from the xml which I'm using because there are problems with rounding"* ? What's the problem with using `sum(//B)`? Can you provide sample XML to demonstrate the 'rounding' problem?

Comment: @har07 So in the xml I have numbers  like this 12.3267 for B with 4 digits after the decimal separator. In the Number the numbers must be rounded to 12.32(this is external requirement). The same is for the SumOfNumberOfB, if I wrote sum(//B) and after that I round it to 2 in some cases there is difference in the sums.

Comment: What did you do for rounding `Number`? If you already have solution to do the rounding to output the correct value for `<Number>`, then I think you can easily apply the same logic for `<SumOfNumberOfB>`...

Comment: The rounding is not done with xslt, it is used C# for that. #0.00 format for the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to round each number, and then form the sum of the rounded numbers, then in XPath 3.0 this can be expressed as

```
sum($numbers ! round(., 2))
```

that is, apply the round() function to each value in $numbers, and then apply the sum() function to the result.

In XPath 2.0 the "!" operator is not available, and there's no round() function with two arguments, so it becomes a little bit more verbose:

```
sum(for $n in $numbers return round-half-to-even($n, 2))
```

In XPath 1.0 it becomes a lot more difficult, because there's no such data type as "a sequence of numbers"; the only thing you can sum over is a node-set, and as you can't create new nodes and process them in XPath, or even in XSLT 1.0, it becomes problematic. You'll find an outline of the possible approaches for XSLT 1.0 here: [Using sum() function for string nodes in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915982/using-sum-function-for-string-nodes-in-xslt/20918809#20918809)