# Sum and translate in one query

Tags: xml, xslt

Now I have got problem with another xml file. In this file amount is in format with comma. I have to sum this amount but before this I have to translate comma on a dot. When I try this I get error that I can`t use this two function i one query. Here some example from my file:

```
<POSITION>
   <LINE ID="1" ID_ARTICLE="1050" QUANTITY="7,2" NET_VALUE="19,44" GROUP_ID="1"/>
   <LINE ID="2" ID_ARTICLE="812" QUANTITY="1,45" NET_VALUE="38,28" GROUP_ID="1"/>
   <LINE ID="1" ID_ARTICLE="852" QUANTITY="8,25" NET_VALUE="31,47" GROUP_ID="2"/>
   <LINE ID="2" ID_ARTICLE="812" QUANTITY="2,58" NET_VALUE="65,87" GROUP_ID="2"/>   
<POSITION>
```

and piece of my transformation xml 1.0 with fonction sum and translate:

```
sum(translate(POSITION/LINE/@NET_VALUE,'.',','))
```

Joel helps me with concat sum and translate, but how to transform Joel`s solution that in finally result looks like this:

```
<GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
<SUM_GROUP_ID>57,72<SUM_GROUP_ID>
<GROUP_ID>2</GROUP_ID>
<SUM_GROUP_ID>97,34<SUM_GROUP_ID>
```

Maybe someone can help me with this problem. I found some solution on this link [Using sum() function for string nodes in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915982/using-sum-function-for-string-nodes-in-xslt) but I can't implement this on my code. I think that someone can translate this solution more understandable for me. I think that I'm still a beginner in xslt, despite writing a few transformations to my clients' files. I am asking for your understanding. Thanks

Comment: *I can't implement this on my code* ... please post your fuller code and not one line snippet. We can then see your implementation.

Comment: Do you use XML 1.0 or XSLT 1.0? If you use XSLT 2 or later you can easily write `sum(/POSITION/LINE/@NET_VALUE/number(translate(., ',', '.')))`. If you are restricted to XSLT 1 it might help to tell us which XSLT 1 processor exactly you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adapted [jelovirt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647991/summing-numbers-with-comma-as-decimal-separator-in-xslt#answer-649492). The stylesheet is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/POSITION">
    <xsl:call-template name="sum">
        <xsl:with-param name="node" select="LINE[1]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sum">
    <xsl:param name="node"/>
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$node">
            <xsl:call-template name="sum">
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$node/following-sibling::LINE[1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + translate($node/@NET_VALUE, ',', '.')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

see if it can solve your problem.

**EDIT**

To achieve the new requirement, I have used `xsl:key` to somehow imitate Muenchian grouping. This is the key:

```
<xsl:key name="kID" match="LINE" use="@GROUP_ID"/>
```

A loop for each unique GROUP_ID, and getting the first element with that unique ID can be presented as

```
<xsl:for-each select="LINE[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('kID', @GROUP_ID)[1])]">
```

Now, as we call the template, we will have to pass the GROUP_ID as an additional parameter, such as

```
<xsl:call-template name="sum">
    <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
    <xsl:with-param name="group" select="@GROUP_ID"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

The whole stylesheet is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kID" match="LINE" use="@GROUP_ID"/>

    <xsl:template match="/POSITION">
        <xsl:for-each select="LINE[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('kID', @GROUP_ID)[1])]">
            <GROUP_ID><xsl:value-of select="@GROUP_ID"/></GROUP_ID>
            <xsl:element name="{concat('SUM_GROUP_ID', @GROUP_ID)}">
                <xsl:call-template name="sum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="group" select="@GROUP_ID"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="sum">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>
        <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
        <xsl:param name="group"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$node">
                <xsl:call-template name="sum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$node/following-sibling::LINE[$group = @GROUP_ID]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + translate($node/@NET_VALUE, ',', '.')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="group" select="@GROUP_ID"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when this is applied to this input:

```
<POSITION>
    <LINE ID="1" ID_ARTICLE="1050" QUANTITY="7,2" NET_VALUE="19,44" GROUP_ID="1"/>
    <LINE ID="2" ID_ARTICLE="812" QUANTITY="1,45" NET_VALUE="38,28" GROUP_ID="1"/>
    <LINE ID="1" ID_ARTICLE="852" QUANTITY="8,25" NET_VALUE="31,47" GROUP_ID="2"/>
    <LINE ID="2" ID_ARTICLE="812" QUANTITY="2,58" NET_VALUE="65,87" GROUP_ID="2"/>   
</POSITION>
```

the desired output is partially achieved. Just replace the dots back with comma.

```
<GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
<SUM_GROUP_ID1>57.72</SUM_GROUP_ID1>
<GROUP_ID>2</GROUP_ID>
<SUM_GROUP_ID2>97.34</SUM_GROUP_ID2>
```

Comment: Joel thanks a lot of this solution. It works perfect. I took me a while to implement this in my code, but It is great solution. In this example I found one more thing. I have to group sum on id_group which it is in all line for example: <LINE ID="1" ID_ARTICLE="1050" QUANTITY="7,2" NET_VALUE="19,44" ID_GROUP="1"/>. Should it be hard for me to adapt this on your solution?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect your new requirement.

Comment: Please see the EDIT part of my answer.

Comment: Joel you are awsome:) Thank you very much for your solution and instruction how It works exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XSLT 2.0 it's easy: see Martin Honnen's comment.

If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, see [Sum of Multiplied Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950703/sum-of-multiplied-values/27954742#27954742)

The reason it's tricky in 1.0 is that there's no data type for a collection of numbers, only a collection of nodes.

Comment: Exactly I use XSLT 1.0 in basic version. On this processor I can use only basic function and more of them I have to write in template.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to move to 2.0.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't move to xslt 2.0 because of the software manufacturer in which I write the transforms, there is only xslt 1.0 and there is not possible to change it on newer version.

Comment: My sympathies. Not quite as bad as being stuck on COBOL, I suppose, but getting close.